# Can matched regex string from replace() be used in the replacement inside concat()? XSLT 2 or 3

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an example xml file where a `<document>` node contains child nodes of one `<docText>` and zero, one or two `<researchNote>`. When the text string [fn:1] occurs I want to replace that with a `<span>` containing the 1st instance of `<researchNote>`, if [fn:2] I want to replace with the second instance of `<researchNote>`. I get this to work for first instance using `replace()` when I either do not include the predicate or statically include the predicate as [1] or [2]. When I try to use the matched string using $1 from the regular expression from the integer matched in the `replace()` I get an error. I would like to find a way in the following XML and XSLT to reference the integer.

This is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
<document id="doc1">
      <docText>This is a test of an inline footnote reference[fn:1]. This is a second[fn:2] footnote.</docText>
      <researchNote>First footnote.</researchNote>
      <researchNote>Second footnote.</researchNote>
</document>
<document id="doc2">
      <docText>This is a test of an inline footnote reference[fn:1].</docText>
      <researchNote>First footnote.</researchNote>
</document>
</project>
```

This is my XSL file. I can use either XSLT 3.0 or 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">

    <xsl:output method="html" html-version="5.0" encoding="utf-8"  indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body><xsl:apply-templates select="project/document/docText"/></body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="docText">
    <p>
    <xsl:variable name="string1" select="replace(.,'\[fn:(\d)\]', concat('&lt;span class=&quot;fn&quot; id=&quot;',concat(ancestor::document/@id,'-fn'),'&quot;&gt; (',ancestor::document/researchNote[1],')&lt;/span&gt;'))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$string1" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would be part of the desired output

```
<p>This is a test of an inline footnote reference<span class="fn" id="doc1-fn"> (First footnote.)</span>. This is a second<span class="fn" id="doc1-fn"> (Second footnote.)</span> footnote.</p>
```

I want to use the number matched in `\[fn:(\d)\]` eg. `$1`, which in this case would be 1 or 2, in the predicate of `ancestor::document/researchNote[]` like this `ancestor::document/researchNote[$1]`. That use gives an error. So, is it possible to do what I want in the replace() function or in a similar manner.

Thanks, Michael

Comment: You should never try to create markup by outputting unescaped text. Instead of`replace()` use `xsl:analyze-string`.

Comment: I agree that creating the html in this fashion is difficult to manage and read, but I've tried other approaches with the help of this forum, and the only successful transformations I've accomplished use replace() on strings and the `&lt;` and `&gt;` references. I've spent months trying to get the others to work and keep having to come back to this. If it were this one simple transformation I think I could get it to work, but this is just a simple example of one step in my process.  If you can think of a way to make this work, It would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the appropriate tool to handle this is the `xsl:analyze-string` instruction, not the `replace()` function which can only output a string result.

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="docText">
    <xsl:variable name="doc" select="ancestor::document" />
    <p>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\[fn:(\d+)\]" >
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <span class="fn" id="{$doc/@id}-fn">
                    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$doc/researchNote[number(regex-group(1))]" />
                    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
                </span>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Working demo: http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zDp/5

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted your first comment to mean I would have to change my approach and not use the unescaped text in order to use the `xsl:analyze-string`. Since the step before and after this in my actual transformation comes from a string and goes to another string, I had to alter your solution above and replace the angle brackets with `&lt;` and `&gt;` and it works now. Thank you for the solution. I wish I understood well enough to avoid my current hack to get this working.

Comment: In trying something similar to this previously, I tried to use `ancestor::document/researchNote` inside the `xsl:analyze-string` which didn't work. Since I was passing a string to `xsl:analyze-string` does that mean the ancestor <document> node was out of scope, if that's the correct terminology?

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me at this point. If your surrounding steps force you to create your own markup, then they too are wrong and need to be fixed - do post separate question/s about them.

Comment: The `xsl:analyze-string` instruction generates a sequence of substrings that is not part of the XML tree being transformed. IOW, in the given example `docText` is not the parent of the matching substring.

Comment: Your comments help, thanks. Using your solution I can get the output I need now. I would agree that my approach is not the correct way to markup the text, but it's the one I've been able to get working. At some point I may try to  redo the whole chain of transformation again. Thanks again for your time and patience. -Michael